# ¿Como reportar una pregunta duplicada cuales no tienen respuesta?

Tags: soporte

Acabo de ver dos preguntas, cuales son idénticas:

- [como-puedo-hacer-doble-filtro-con-2-combobox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41809/como-puedo-hacer-doble-filtro-con-2-combobox)
- [trato-de-filtrar-dos-veces-con-comboboxs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41813/trato-de-filtrar-dos-veces-con-comboboxs)

y con diferentes usuarios (pero esto es otro tema).

Quería reportarlo como duplicado pero no me deja ya que no tienen respuestas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como reportar estos casos?

¿Porque esperar que haya respuesta(s), si lo que no queremos son duplicados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pon un reporte de tipo "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" y en la caja explicas el problema y pones el enlace a la posible pregunta duplicada. Nosotros podemos cerrar este tipo de preguntas.

La pregunta que indicas ya fue cerrada como duplicada.